# Как убрать Status Bar?

Tags: android

В разработке приложения нужно убрать показ StatusBar (строка состояния с часами в правом углу - самый верхний край экрана) во всех окнах. Возможно ли такое?

Comment: Быть может `ActionBar`? Уточните вопрос. Что Вы имеете в виду под `StatusBar`?

Comment: Это строка состояния с часами в правом углу (самый верхний край экрана).

Comment: Теперь понятно. Только лучше это уточнение добавить в сам вопрос, чтобы участникам сообщества сразу было всё понятно. Для этого есть "кнопка" под названием "править".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перегрузите любую тему и добавьте:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно убрать строку с часами и т.д. (строку состояния) в самой верхней части экрана, можно воспользоваться предопределёнными стилями Android для `Activity`.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Этот стиль должен убрать строку состояния, но сохранить заголовок (`ActionBar`) `Activity`.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Этот стиль должен убрать и строку состояния и заголовок `Activity` (по сути, переводит Activity в полноэкранный режим).

Answer (score 0):

В Kotlin'e можно скрыть / убрать status Bar указав в onCreate:

```
initializeNoStatusBar(false)
```